# Scala for-comprehension if filtering too much?

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I have the following program: (Scala 2.9.2, Java6)

```
object Forcomp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val xs = List(-1, 0, 1)
    val xss = for (a <- xs; b <- xs if a != 0 && b != 0) yield (a,b)
    println(xss)
  }
}
```

It produces this output: `List((-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,-1), (1,1))`
I would have expected it to only filter out values where `a` and `b` are *both* 0 – not all values where *either* `a` or `b` are 0.

I can get the behaviour I want by changing the if-clause to this: `if (a,b) != (0,0)` – however, should I really have to? Is this a bug or is this intentional behaviour? I, for one, was surprised by this.

Comment: You need to use `!(a==0 && b==0)` to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: Or `a != 0 || b != 0` which is basically [the same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The truth table for the filter you have is this:

```
 a==0  |  b==0 | (a!=0 && b!=0)
--------------------------------
  0    |   0   |      0
  0    |   1   |      0
  1    |   0   |      0
  1    |   1   |      1
```

whereas the behaviour you say you want is:

```
 a==0  |  b==0 | !(a==0 && b==0)
--------------------------------
  0    |   0   |      0
  0    |   1   |      1
  1    |   0   |      1
  1    |   1   |      1
```